# Проблема уязвимостей высокой степени серьезности при установке и настройке GULP

Tags: gulp, gulp4

Устанавливаю GULP файл, командой `npm i gulp -D` выдаёт такой результат:

```
added 351 packages, and audited 352 packages in 29s

13 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

По рекомендации пользуюсь командой `npm audit fix` выдаёт такой ответ:

```
up to date, audited 352 packages in 5s

13 packages are looking for funding   
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service in enclosure regex 
- https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gulp@3.9.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/chokidar
    glob-watcher  >=3.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/glob-watcher
      gulp  >=4.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-watcher
      Depends on vulnerable versions of vinyl-fs
      node_modules/gulp
  glob-stream  5.3.0 - 6.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/glob-stream
    vinyl-fs  >=2.4.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-stream
   node_modules/vinyl-fs

6 high severity vulnerabilities
```

То есть я так понимаю угрозы зависимостей не исчезают, потом игнорируя их устанавливаю npm пакеты, а этих угроз становится всё больше и больше, хотя у людей, которые занимаются обучением из разных источников их нет, как исправить данную ошибку?